# Websocket 'onmessage' logger to MongoDB

Tags: javascript, performance, node.js, logging, websocket

I'm learning websockets and wanted to make a websocket `onmessage` logger which writes the received data in a mongodb.

I'm starting my script with

```
node listner.js
```

*listner.js:*

```
'use strict';

let DBAbstract = require('./db-controller');
const WebSocket = require('ws');

// getting an instance of a mongodb connection
let mongoInstance = new DBAbstract();

const ws = new WebSocket('ws://ws-url');

ws.onopen = function() {
  console.log('Open')
};
ws.onmessage = function(d) {
  console.log(d.data)
  mongoInstance.insertOne(JSON.parse(d.data)) //Promise which add the data
};

ws.onclose = function() {
  console.log('Close')
  //maybe a reconnect attempt ?
};

ws.onerror = function(e) {
  console.log(e.code)
};
```

I made this script so far and it works.

When there is an `onmessage` Event I'm getting a small JSON like this.

```
{ "event":2,
  "value": 12,
  "item": 'Spoon' }
```

I was just wondering if this is might be enough in terms of scalability of the received `onmessage` Events.

I mean there is no problem when I receive three times of small-JSON's in 10 seconds. What will happen when I'm receiving 1000 small-JSON's in 10 seconds ?

Can I improve this code ?